# Open/Public Data Sources For Land-Cover/Vegetation Data In The Provinces of British Columbia and Alberta, Canada?

Tags: geospatial, canada, land

The title is quite clear: seeking land-cover/vegetation open/public data sources for the Canadian Provinces of British Columbia, and Alberta.

**Note:**
This question was originally posted in the [The Spatial Community - GIS Devs Slack Channel](https://gisdevs.slack.com/)

Answer (score 1):

### Resources List

[Land Cover Institute (Global)](http://landcover.usgs.gov/landcoverdata.php)
[North American Land Cover Data Links - Land Cover Institute](http://landcover.usgs.gov/landcoverdata.php#na)
[Geospatial Data: Land Cover & Land Use of Canada](http://leddy.uwindsor.ca/adc/geospatial-data-canada-landcover)
[Natural Resources Canada](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/home)
[Characterization and Monitoring Change of Canada’s Land Surface](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/land-surface-vegetation/land-cover/north-american-landcover/9146)
["Land Cover" Search Results - Natural Resources Canada](http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/-/(urn:gc:subject)land-management?q=land+cover&sort-field=relevance)
[Land Cover and Vegetation - Natural Resources Canada](http://www.nrcan.gc.ca/earth-sciences/geomatics/satellite-imagery-air-photos/applications-development/land-cover-vegetation)
[Medium Resolution Land Cover Mapping of Canada from Spot 4/5 Data](http://geoscan.nrcan.gc.ca/starweb/geoscan/servlet.starweb?path=geoscan/fulle.web&search1=R=295751)
[British Columbia Data Catalogue](https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset?download_audience=Public)
["Land Cover" Search Results of British Columbia Data Catalogue](https://catalogue.data.gov.bc.ca/dataset?q=land+cover&download_audience=Public&sort=score+desc%2C+record_publish_date+desc)
[Alberta Ground Cover Classification Mosaic Status](https://geodiscover.alberta.ca/geoportal/catalog/search/resource/details.page?uuid=%7B673F26CF-C97C-4668-8C26-CCD5E6EDE9A7%7D)
[Land Information Ontario Metadata Management Tool](https://www.javacoeapp.lrc.gov.on.ca/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home)
[RT Wilson's GIS List Has Land Cover and Canadian Sections](http://freegisdata.rtwilson.com/)
[Canada Clearinghouse and Portals](http://gis.ubc.ca/data-sources-2/canada/)
[AVHRR Land Cover Data, Canada-British Columbia](http://geogratis.gc.ca/api/en/nrcan-rncan/ess-sst/9adb5aec-9a6a-520e-b947-b2dc4fa6a7cd.html)